# Response for Preflight occuring only for application/json

Tags: spring, cors, angular5, content-type, preflight

I have been trying to do a post request from angular 5 to my spring mvc backend. However, I am getting the Response for preflight is inavlid(redirect) error message. I have been looking around for solution since 4 days but with no success. I have tried all suggestions setting the content-type headers. While doing that, I am observing one unusual thing. The preflight error is occuring only when I am setting the content-type header is set to application/json. If I set the header to text/plain the preflight error is gone but 415 unsupported media type error is being displayed. I have been really digging up stuff to get some help. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using chrome, look at Developer tools - console and see the exact error.

Your service is not setting preflight response correctly for your OPTIONS request.

### How can i verify if my service is CORS ready

1. use PostMan or RestClient and make an OPTIONS request with nothing else (no auth, nothing)
2. Look for Response headers for OPTIONS request from Step 1.
3. Response headers may look like this

#### Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://exampledomain.comg

#### Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST (or whatever methods your want to allow)

#### Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

Comment: if I change the content-type to text/plain preflight error is avoided but then I have to deal with 415 unsupported media type.

Comment: are you the service owner? If not you will need to be in touch with them

Comment: are you able to see content type on allow-headers in options response?

Comment: I tried doing the post request through Postman, by setting the authorization header to NTLM and passed by object with the request, and it returned with status 200 ok. So, it's the authorization that is causing the problem i guess. Now I am just wondering how can I add the same authorization header with NTLM through angular and pass it on to backend to complete the post request successfully.

Comment: I can see the content-type as application/json in response

Answer (score 0):

***Add crossOrigin Annotation at your controller,  if you have more one controller then add on  all controller***

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
```